# Find Principal Part Of $\frac{ze^{iz}}{(z^2+9)^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the principal part  of $\frac{ze^{iz}}{(z^2+9)^2}$ at $z_0=3i$

Can I say that $$\frac{ze^{iz}}{(z^2+9)^2}=\frac{\frac{ze^{iz}}{(z+3i)^2}}{(z-3i)^2}$$

And look at $g(z)=\frac{ze^{iz}}{(z+3i)^2}$?

Comment: The principal part is zero as the function's analytic at $\;z=3i\;$...

Comment: You *could* say that if it was true, but it isn't. What *is* true is that$$\frac{ze^{iz}}{(z^2+9)^2}=\frac{\frac{ze^{iz}}{(z+3i)^2}}{(z-3i)^2}.$$Perhaps that you meant$$\frac{ze^{iz}}{z^2+9}.$$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Also what you say *is true* isn't...It'd be if you'd write $\;\sqrt z\;$ instead of $\;z\;$ in the right hand.

Comment: Sorry I have fixed it

Comment: @newhere Now that you've corrected that you can then say what you said and be right...

Comment: I've fixed my comment too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Set $w=z-3i$ and then
$$\frac{ze^{iz}}{(z^2+9)^2}=\frac{(w+3i)e^{iw-3}}{w^4(1+\frac{6i}{w})^2}$$
with the expansions
$$e^u=1+u+\dfrac{u^2}{2!}+\dfrac{u^3}{3!}+\dfrac{u^2}{4!}+\cdots$$
and
$$\dfrac{1}{(1+u)^2}=1-2u+3u^2-\cdots$$

Comment: How did $$\dfrac{1}{(1+u)^2}=1-2u+3u^2-\cdots$$

Comment: differentiate $\dfrac{1}{1+u}=1-u+u^2+\cdots$

Comment: if $|u|<1$ and taking it to power of $2$ results $1+u^2+u^4+...$?

Comment: Hey, try again!

Comment: $(\frac{1}{1+u})'=-\frac{1}{(1+u)^2}?$

Comment: yeah, it is . . .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80301/discussion-between-user-108128-and-newhere).

Answer (score 1):

Note that both parts $\frac{1}{(z-3i)^2}$ as well as $g(z)$ contribute to  the  principal part of the function.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{ze^{iz}}{(z^2+9)^2}&=\frac{1}{(z-3i)^2}\cdot\frac{ze^{iz}}{(z+3i)^2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{(z-3i)^2}\cdot\frac{ze^{iz}}{(6i+z-3i)^2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{(z-3i)^2}\cdot\frac{ze^{iz}}{(6i)^2\left(1+\frac{z-3i}{6i}\right)^2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{(z-3i)^2}\cdot\frac{\left[3i+(z-3i)\right]e^{i(z-3i+3i)}}{-36}
> \sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{-2}{n}\left(\frac{z-3i}{6i}\right)^n\tag{1}\\
> &=\left(-\frac{i}{12e^3(z-3i)^2}-\frac{1}{36e^3(z-3i)}\right)e^{i(z-3i)}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{-2}{n}\left(\frac{z-3i}{6i}\right)^n\tag{2}\\
> &=\left(-\frac{i}{12e^3(z-3i)^2}-\frac{1}{36e^3(z-3i)}\right)\\
> &\qquad\qquad\cdot\left(1+i(z-3i)+\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(i(z-3i))^n}{n!}\right)\\
> &\qquad\qquad\cdot\left(1-\frac{1}{3i}(z-3i)+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\binom{-2}{n}\left(\frac{z-3i}{6i}\right)^n\right)\tag{3}\\
> &=\color{blue}{-\frac{i}{12e^3(z-3i)^2}+\frac{1}{12e^3(z-3i)}}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-3i)^n\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* and prepare the numerator for expansion at $z-3i$.
- In (2) we do some simplifications and separate the relevant terms with negative powers.
- In (3) we separate the constant and linear terms of the power series which contribute to the principal part.
- In (4) we multiply out and obtain the (blue colored) principal part.